# Current concerns when soldering

Tags: pcb, current, soldering

I am making a SP3T switch that has PU/PD/Load.  One of these is an automotive injector that would see some intermittent current with a max of 16A @ 85V.

Is it dangerous to use solder to connect this terminals together on a pcb?
Is copper trace what I would need to opt for?
I am just worried about the current being too high and not really sure of solder's capability for this.
I am not using a PCB designer.

Comment: Where are your thermal calculations?

Comment: I soldered battery cables and connections for currents greater than 800 or 1000A - they did not melt the solder - but if you have a bad or high resistance connection the situation changes...

Answer (score 0):

High current traces must be. Wide and Short . Use Saturn’s free PCB executable tool to calculate the voltage drop per mm length for a given track width and copper weight with solder plating thickness. If excessive you may need to reinforce with short 16-24AWG wire soldered to tracks for power , ground return and drive signals.  Keep loop area of all current loops to a practical minimum by every means due to switched inductive loads.